# Get graphics in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, graphics, regression

I want to create a personal web application using Django for the backend and Vue.js for the frontend, but I need to know if it is possible to use graphics in Vue.js, is that possible?
In my application, I want to implement regression functions in Django to visualise the output in graphics in Vue.js and I want also to show the data flow of some features of my data.

Is this possible?

I haven't tried to do anything yet because it is all a working progress.

Comment: you mean like a canvas? or svg? "graphics" is such a useless word

Comment: I mean like matplotlib on python

Comment: Yeah, sure, sounds like perfectly doable

Comment: How can I do that? I mean, which library shell I use on Vue.js to have plots like matplotlib or seaborn ?

Comment: yeah, use a library that does what you need I guess